# vfw.h no longer present on RHEL 4.8?

Tags: redhat, video, gcc

I maintain an application which relies on vfw. Unfortunately, I am not able to remove this deprecated video encoding mechanism at this time. My application compiles fine on Windows, but on RHEL 4.8 it does not, even though it used to like a month ago. Has RHEL finally fully deprecated this? This used to compile like a month or two ago. The error I get is:

include/avi.h:9:17: vfw.h: No such file or directory

I realize that video for windows has long been deprecated by Microsoft, and expecting it to be supported in Linux is kind of crazy. However, I find it odd that the header files, and supporting libraries, would simply be gone due to normal system maintenance. My source including vfw.h has not been modified for four years, we have not included vfw.h in our revision control system. This leads me to believe that vfw.h used to be a system header, but no longer is on RHEL 4.8. VS2008 is able to find it no problem. I'm in the process of going through our build system snapshots, but I am not having any luck locating vfw.h anywhere. I am posting this here because I believe this is a system level include issue related to system administration.

Does anyone have an idea of what is going on? Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

```
[flow3d@x64-RHEL48-BUILD gfx3d]$ gcc -v
Reading specs from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6/specs
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --
infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --disable-checking -with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-java-awt=gtk --host=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-11)

[flow3d@x64-RHEL48-BUILD gfx3d]$ uname -r 
2.6.9-103.EL

[flow3d@x64-RHEL48-BUILD gfx3d]$ lsb_release
LSB Version:    :core-3.0-amd64:core-3.0-ia32:core-3.0-noarch:graphics-3.0-amd64:graphics-3.0-ia32:graphics-3.0-noarch

[flow3d@x64-RHEL48-BUILD gfx3d]$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux WS release 4 (Nahant Update 9)
```

Comment: Something happened within my code base and build system. If I check out a previous version on my same system, I don't receive this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vfw.h file is part of the `wine-devel` package.

Comment: Odd... Why would this suddenly go away? I'll take a look at wine-devel. Thanks.

Comment: This was totally a problem with my build system, and unrelated to vfw.h. We had made massive changes to our system, and this broke the:

# non-win32 specific stuff
!win32{
    SOURCES -=$${SOURCE_DIR}/avi.cpp
    HEADERS -=$${INCLUDE_DIR}/avi.h
}

stuff I had going on in my .pro file. Likely, I'll delete this question in a few days, as the entire premise for asking it was incorrect.

Comment: But the file is traditionally part of the `wine-devel` CentOS package as well.